# Matrix Exponential and Modal matrix Connection Problem

Tags: matrices

if there is a matrix A from State-Space and we have 
$$
T^{-1}AT = \Lambda = \text{diag} \{s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n\}
$$
how can I prove that 
$$
e^{At} = T^{-1} \Lambda T - 1
$$
????
thanks

Comment: Hello - welcome to math.stackexchange. I have edited your question using \TeX. Please look over the problem again since in this form the statement is not correct. Also, please tell us what you have done so far and what related problems you can solve.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $T^{-1} e^{At} T = e^{\Lambda t}$.  The formula you have doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you want to show is incorrect. We have $A=T\Lambda T^{-1}$ and hence 
$$
e^{At}
=I + At + \frac1{2!}(At)^2 + \ldots
=T\left(I + \Lambda t + \frac1{2!}(\Lambda t)^2 + \ldots\right)T^{-1}
=Te^{\Lambda t}T^{-1}.
$$
So, when $t$ is small, you can approximate $e^{At}$ by dropping the quadratic or higher-order terms in $t$ in the above infinite series. Hence $e^{At}\approx I + At = I+tT\Lambda T^{-1}$. Note that this is different from the expression you give: it's $T\Lambda T^{-1}$ instead of $T^{-1}\Lambda T$, and the matrix product is also multiplied by $t$.